# Condition as function in for comprehension loop

Tags: scala, slick

I would like to use a custom condition function in my for-comprehension loop for slick query:

```
def findNewsletterUsers(f: (NewsletterUsers, NewsletterStatuses) => Boolean) = {
    for {
      u <- NewsletterUsers
      s <- NewsletterStatuses if (u.statusId === s.id)
      d <- NewsletterDelays if (u.delayId === d.id)
      if f(u, s)
    } yield (u, d, s)
  }
```

I would like to invoke this method with actual custom condition filled in a layer above. Something like:

```
findNewsletterUsers((nu, ns) => ns.name == 'C')
```

This invocation returns no rows though (while it should). Is there any way to make it work that way?

Best regards

Comment: why does your `f`  take `NewsletterUsers, NewsletterStatuses` (plural) instead of `NewsletterUser, NewsletterStatus` (singular) ?

Comment: Is your `ns.name` a `String` or a `Char`?

Comment: These go from slick database generation model - slick-codegen. It introduces case class NewsletterStatusesRow(id: Long, name: Char, description: Option[String] = None) and class NewsletterStatuses(_tableTag: Tag) extends Table[NewsletterStatusesRow](_tableTag, "newsletter_statuses") and lazy val NewsletterStatuses = new TableQuery(tag => new NewsletterStatuses(tag))

Comment: ns.name is a Char

Comment: My advice is to create a [minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)  that will isolate the problem. Conceptually from the strict Scala perspective, what you are doing is correct. I just recreated your use case with Options instead of Newsletter stuff and everything is as expected, no surprises. One of the possible causes of error could be that `u <- NewsletterUsers` yields a yet another `NewsletterUsers` as `u`. Is this as intended? Flatmapping over `NewsletterUsers[T]` gives you a `T`, so it seems as if you have `NewsletterUsers[NewsletterUsers]]`, which is weird.

Comment: Also try it without those two if-guards for IDs. Perhaps your IDs are simply not matching so the for comprehension stops there at some point and nothing is returned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An easy mistake to make in slick is to use the `==` operator instead of the `===` operator.

In your case you use the function `(nu, ns) => ns.name == 'C')`. This function always returns false because ns.name is not a `Char` but a `Rep[Char]`.

To solve this issue, you simply need to replace `==` by `===`, slick will automatically lift the literal char `'C'` to a `Rep[Char]`.

Comment: Seems like the root of evil indeed :) but how to fix the invocation then? It seems that findNewsletterUsers((nu, ns) => ns.name === Rep['C']) is not possible.

Comment: Stick can automatically convert literals to a Rep (or actually a ConstColumn). So you can use `ns.name === 'C'` (with triple equals instead of double). (also updated this in the answer above)

Comment: Working! I needed to change my function declaration to def findNewsletterUsers(f: (NewsletterUsers, NewsletterStatuses) => Rep[Boolean]) = {,,,, and it's working. Thank you for your help!